# Threading and Networking

Tags: python, multithreading, networking, chatroom

I don't know how to make it that when there are multiple people connected to my python server to be able to input a message and see it instantly without the other person needing to press enter to see it. How would I use threading here?

Server:

```
import socket, thread

def reactor(sock,client,data):
        try:
           sock.sendto(data.encode('utf-8'),client)
           sock.close()
        except Exception,e :
            print(e)
            sock.close()

def Main():
    host = '25.4.221.63'
    port = 5000

    clients = []


    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind((host,port))

    print("Server Started")
    while True:
        data,addr=s.recvfrom(1024)
        if addr not in clients:
            clients.append(addr)
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        print("Message From: " + str(addr))
        print("From connected user: " + data)
        print("Sending: " + data)
        for client in clients:
            try:
                thread.start_new_thread(reactor,(s,client,data))
            except Exception,e :
                print(e)
                s.close()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Client:

```
import socket

def Main():
    alias = input("ScreenName:")
    inp = input("IP:")

    host =inp
    port = 5001

    server = ('25.4.221.63',5000)

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind((host,port))

    message = input("-> ")

    while message != 'q':
        s.sendto(message.encode('utf-8'), server)
        data,addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        print(data)
        message = input(alias + ' -> ')
    s.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: Probably not a good idea to post your real IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid threads; use `select`.

You should use `select` or `epoll` to simultaneously wait for input from either the socket or stdin. If `select` indicates the socket is ready for reading, read your message. If stdin is ready for reading, read the user input. This will require implementing `input` yourself.

Comment: One potential gotcha (depending on the original poster's use case):  select()/poll() on stdin won't work under Windows.